Nextjs cannot find ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
im trying to run nextjs using the base image ruby:2.7.1-alpine and installing node like this:
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /opt/yarn-v1.22.19 /opt/yarn-v1.22.19
RUN \
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js /usr/local/bin/corepack \
    && ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm \
    && ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npx \
    && ln -s /opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
    && ln -s /opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg

But when i run the container with enterypoint pnpm dev im met with this error:
Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu, but an error occurred: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /app/node_modules/.pnpm/@next+swc-linux-x64-gnu@14.2.5/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu/next-swc.linux-x64-gnu.node)
Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-musl, but an error occurred: Error relocating /app/node_modules/.pnpm/@next+swc-linux-x64-musl@14.2.5/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-musl/next-swc.linux-x64-musl.node: pthread_getname_np: symbol not found
⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for linux/x64, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

Although this command ln -s /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 returns the the file already exists.
I've tried installing glibc compatibility like this:
ENV GLIBC_VERSION="2.35-r0"
RUN curl -Lo /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
    curl -Lo /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && \
    curl -Lo /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && \
    apk add --no-cache /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && \
    rm /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk

and this:
RUN apk add gcompat
To no avail.
This is the whole Dockerfile:
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine AS base

# install nodejs 
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /opt/yarn-v1.22.19 /opt/yarn-v1.22.19
RUN \
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js /usr/local/bin/corepack \
    && ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm \
    && ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npx \
    && ln -s /opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
    && ln -s /opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg

# install build dependencies and needed tools
RUN apk add \
    wget \
    gcc \
    make \
    zlib-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    musl-dev \
    curl

# Install ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
# Install glibc compatibility for Alpine
ENV GLIBC_VERSION="2.35-r0"
RUN curl -Lo /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
    curl -Lo /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && \
    curl -Lo /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && \
    apk add --no-cache /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && \
    rm /tmp/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk /tmp/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk


RUN npm install -g pnpm
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i
    

COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
COPY next.config.mjs .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY ./.npmrc .
COPY ./tailwind.config.ts .
COPY postcss.config.mjs .


# you can specify python version during image build
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.11.4

# download and extract python sources
RUN cd /opt \
    && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz \                                              
    && tar xzf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz

# build python and remove left-over sources
RUN cd /opt/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} \ 
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install \
    && make install \
    && rm /opt/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz /opt/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} -rf

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    build-base \
    openblas-dev

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# Install the specified Python packages
RUN pip3 install \
    xlsxwriter>=3.1.2 \
    pandas>=2.0.2 \
    openpyxl>=3.1.2 \
    numpy>=1.25.0

# Install Rubygems version 2.7.4
RUN gem update --system 2.7.4

# Install Asciidoctor PDF and Asciidoctor Diagram
RUN gem install public_suffix -v 5.1.1
RUN gem install asciidoctor-pdf -v 1.6.2 \
    && gem install asciidoctor-diagram -v 2.2.1

# Start Next.js in development mode based on the preferred package manager
CMD \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn dev; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run dev; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then pnpm dev; \
    else npm run dev; \
    fi

